# RollingFile appender with file name to be determined at each logger invocation

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I have a function which executes HTTP request/response and I would like to log the content of them.

Such code can be invoked multiple times within the same execution (classified by an "executionId") and each time can have a different "activityId".

What I would like to get is:

- A new log file each time the executionId changes (so having `execution1.log`, `execution2.log`, `execution3.log` etc.)
- To append into the potentially already existing file all logs for the same execution id (so if file `execution1.log` has already been created and I'm asked to log again something when `executionId == execution1`, then appending to that file).

With this purpose in mind, I have configured the following `log4j2.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <properties>
        <property name="logDir">logs/</property>
    </properties>
    <appenders>
        <RollingFile name="HttpActivityTracingAppender" filePattern="${logDir}/http-logs/${ctx:executionId}.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} [%t] %c [execution:%X{executionId},activity:%X{activityId}] : %p - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <logger name="HttpActivityTracing" level="trace">
            <appender-ref ref="HttpActivityTracingAppender"/>
        </logger>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

... and then I'm invoking the logger as follows:

```
    ThreadContext.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    ThreadContext.putAll(Map.of("executionId", ..., "activityId", ...);
    ThreadContext.pop();
    myLogger.trace("bla bla bla");
    ThreadContext.clearAll();
```

The result is that the first time `executionId` is defined (let's say `execution1`), then a log file named `execution1.log` is created under `logs/` as expected.

However, on consecutive executions with new values of `executionId`, I see the new `executionId` inside the log file but the name of the file used is still `execution1.log`.

So for example, inside `execution1.log` I will find stuff like:

```
2022-09-20T22:52:02,639 [main] HttpActivityTracing [execution:execution1,activity:activity1] : TRACE - ... (ok)
2022-09-20T22:52:02,639 [main] HttpActivityTracing [execution:execution1,activity:activity2] : TRACE - ... (ok)
2022-09-20T22:52:02,639 [main] HttpActivityTracing [execution:execution1,activity:activity3] : TRACE - ... (ok)
2022-09-20T22:52:02,639 [main] HttpActivityTracing [execution:execution2,activity:activity1] : TRACE - ... (NO, I WANT THIS INTO ANOTHER FILE "execution2.log")
2022-09-20T22:52:02,639 [main] HttpActivityTracing [execution:execution2,activity:activity2] : TRACE - ... (NO, I WANT THIS INTO ANOTHER FILE "execution2.log")
```

I have found several examples all over the web but I couldn't make this one work, I feel I'm not far but I can't make it work.

Can anyone please help?

P.s. I've tried to use `fileName` instead of `filePattern` in the `RollingFile` appender configuration, but it tries to create a file with the name `${ctx:executionId}` in it which ends up being rejected by Windows because it contains an illegal character `:`.

Comment: It sounds, like you "just" need "dynamic file appender(s)", (no word about ["rolling"](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender)..) If maximum number of executions is "overviewable" (let's say 3): configure multiple appenders(/loggers) and switch/use them, when you log... Otherwise/in any case: you can programmatically edit (&refresh) the configuration [link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#AddingToCurrent)

Comment: [Routing-](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) and [ScriptAppenderSelector](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#ScriptAppenderSelector) seem also usable for this case.

Comment: Neither Routing nor ScriptAppenderSelector can do it unfortunately because the executionId is a random UUID, it's impossible to anticipate the name or how many of them they will be. The only one which seems appropriate for my case is to refresh the configuration, but after doing it nothing happens (it's like if I didn't write any code)

Comment: @xerx593 your programmatically refresh link ended up helping me somehow! You can check the answer I posted to see how I solved (it's not really what your link says but it goes in the same direction). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue with the exact same configuration than illustrated in the question, plus the following two lines of code **after** the `ThreadContext.pop()`:

```
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    context.reconfigure();
```